# When FCM refreshes a reg token, will the old one still work for a period of time without errors?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

At https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#admin_sdk_error_reference, it says we will get a `registration-token-not-registered` if FCM has refreshed the token and we are sending to the old one.

I'm concerned about the race condition where the token is refreshed, but the android app hasn't been able to get the new registration key to the app server yet, and we try to send a notification from the app server using the old registration key. Will we get a `registration-token-not-registered` in this case, or is there a grace period where the old registration key will still work to give us time to receive the new key?

Answer (score 0):

In my logs I found a refreshed token from 20 or so days ago, and when I messaged the old token it was accepted without error, so the answer is YES, old reg keys will continue to work for a period of time without errors, so we don't need to worry about this race condition:)